# XNA Vertices don't appear when the camera is at 0,0,0

Tags: xna, camera, vertices

I have, what I think is going to be a very obvious question to some so I'm hoping someone could quickly clean it up for me. I have an XNA app where I draw a grid of vertices and the camera is positioned 20.0f above it. If I place the camera at 0, -20, 0 and the target at 0, 0, 0 then the vertices don't appear. If I adjust the X or the Z axis a little bit to 0.1 then the vertices show. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample code of this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, the most likely reason is because your view matrix's up vector is parallel with the direction your camera is looking. If your camera is at 0,-20,0 and your target is 0,0,0 and your up vector is 0,1,0 then that parallel situation will occur. Offsetting the position or target slightly removes this parallel situation.

When you run CreateLookAt(), the behind the scenes framework code crosses the up vector with the direction the camera is looking (target - position). If the two vectors that are being crossed are parallel, it returns a zero length vector result which breaks the view matrix.

moral:
Never let your up vector be parallel to the direction the camera is looking.

Comment: Sorry, but I have another question now. I understand the Up vector is whatever is "Up" based on your camera view. I'm trying to make a birds eye view, where the Z axis is up and down, and X is left and right. From my understanding the "Up" vector should be -1 on the Z axis, but when I do that +X on the X axis is left and -X on the axis is right. If I change the up vector to 1 on the Z axis this corrects it, but it makes me confused because shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Picture yourself floating a couple hundred feet above the ground looking straight down with your top of your head pointing north. To your right the earth's longitudes decrease. Now picture yourself a couple hundred feet below ground level looking up at the surface with the top of your head again pointing north. now to your right, the longitudes increase. In your situ, you've placed the camera below ground ( -20 ) so it is like being below ground level.

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks. After you explained it made me realise another error of mine. I didn't mean for it to be -20, but to be 20. I thought -20 would be placing it in the sky, not under the ground. Although, I have 1 more quick question now which I hope you don't mind answering (sorry haha), when I change it to 20 instead of -20, all of the vertices completely vanish. I assume it's going to be something silly that you can quickly answer like the up vector thing, do you have any ideas?

Comment: most likely it is because of backface culling where it doesn't draw triangles that are facing away from the camera for performance sake. The best solution is to run the vertices through the GPU in the opposite order, then it will think the triangles are facing the opposite direction. Or you can create a new RasterizerState object and set the cull mode to a different setting.